# How to rotate a 2D OpenGL object with a BMP image (Texture)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, opengl-es

I tried the following code to rotate an image but it didn't work.

Whenever I write down this code it doesn't work, I'm not sure but I'm suspicious that the problem happens in this line (Although it doesn't show an error that points to it) : rotatingkiller[i]->display(rotatingObjects[i].points[3].x + rotatingObjects[i].ceta, rotatingObjects[i].points[3].y + rotatingObjects[i].ceta);

The error happens on a separate window, a popup error window.

```
Image *rotatingkiller[1];
void LoadImages()
{
rotatingkiller[0] = new Image("satoor.bmp");
}

void myDisplay()
{
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
 glColor3f(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity();
 glPointSize(4.0);
 glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

for (int i = 0; i < rotatingObjects.size(); i++)
 {
  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(775, 475, 0);
  glRotatef(rotatingObjects[0].ceta, 0, 0, 1);
  glTranslatef(-775, -475, 0);
  rotatingkiller[i]->display(rotatingObjects[i].points[3].x + rotatingObjects[i].ceta, rotatingObjects[i].points[3].y + rotatingObjects[i].ceta);
  rotatingObjects[i].Draw();
  glPopMatrix();
  glutSwapBuffers();
 }
glFlush();
}
void update(int value)
{
 rotatingObjects[0].ceta += 15;
 glutPostRedisplay();
 glutTimerFunc(80, update, 0);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 glutInit(&argc, argv);
 glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH); 
 glutInitWindowSize(1000, 600);
 glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);
 glutCreateWindow("Jumping Rabbit");
 myStyleInit();
 loadImages();
 InsertShapes();
 glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
 glutSpecialFunc(keyboard);
 for (int i = 0; i < movingObjects.size(); i++){ 
  printf("%d", movingObjects.size());
  glutTimerFunc(movingObjects[i].movmentSpeed, myTimer, i);
  printf("%d", i);
 }
 PlaySound(TEXT("gamestart.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC);
 glutTimerFunc(25, update, 0);
 glutMainLoop();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the problem that the program crashes or that no rotation happens? `i` goes from `0 to rotatingObjects.size()` but you use `rotatingkiller[i]`. Are they the same size?

Comment: Why are you calling `glutSwapBuffers();` for a single-buffered window?

Comment: @pingul The program crashes, and yes they are the same size.

Comment: @pingul the point is that the object rotate if no texture -image-  is applied on it.

Comment: but if the the texture is applied, the program crash and nothing happens.

Comment: It's hard for us to track the problem down without you providing the debug information. As you say that no error is shown, I'm guessing it's a `Segfault`, which would mean you're accessing invalid memory. Is `.points[3]` valid?